# jQuery smooth scrolling, add a class of active to anchor when the page is scrolled to the respective section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using smooth scroll functionality on my page for internal links. I am using something as follows: (note: the menu will be fixed on top of the page and each a tag will be used to jump to that section of the current page)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#mission">Our Mission</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
....
<section id="home"><!-- content goes here --></section>
..
<section id="about"><!-- content goes here --></section>
..
<section id="mission"><!-- content goes here --></section>
..
<section id="contact"><!-- content goes here --></section>
..
```

I am using the following jQuery script to implement the smooth scroll effect:

```
      $(function() {
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

This works fine, but what I want is for a way that when the user scrolls to say, section#mission i want a class of active added to the a href="#mission". Using this class i would specify styles(background color) for the current active anchor tag.

I want to know how this can be done? I would prefer a jQuery approach.

Thank you for your time.

**Made a Fiddle here with which you can work on easily:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/umehyrza/

Comment: Do you want to add the styles to the `a` tag if the user scrolls to the element without clicking on the `a` tag?

Comment: yes, the click should not matter, but the styles (for example a background color) should be added to the a tag when the page is on the element with the id's specified in the menu.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:target`:

```css
section:target {background: #99f;}
```

And don't forget to add that to the `location`.

```
location.hash = id;
```

The script for you:

```
if (target.length) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 1000);
  location.hash = target;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: will this add the background color to the section or to the a tag? i want the background color to be added to the a tag. Can you please make a fiddle, I would highly appreciate it and will gladly accept this as the answer.

Comment: sorry if that sounds a bit too much work.  I have made a fiddle here for your convenience with which you can work easily:

https://jsfiddle.net/umehyrza/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirement of the question. You are adding the background color on the section of the page. Please look at Mohamed-Yousef's answer, he understood the requirement

Comment: Okay lemme think in a better way. You know what, you can use ScrollSpy to achieve that. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                $(".nav > li > a").removeClass("newClass");
                $(this).addClass("newClass");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("section").each(function(){
            if(ScrollView($(this))){
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $(".nav > li > a").removeClass("newClass");
                $(".nav > li > a[href='#" + id + "']").addClass("newClass");
            }
        });
    });
    function ScrollView(element){
        var win = $(window);
        var winTop = win.scrollTop();
        var winBottom = winTop + win.height();
        var elementTop = element.offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + element.height();

        if((elementBottom <= winBottom) && (elementTop >= winTop)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JacquesMarais/umehyrza/6/).

Comment: this is really good, Jacques. just a small thing I noticed, a little flicker on the color from the time it is clicked until the time it reaches its destination. any idea how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 2):

you need window scroll event to do that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var WindowTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('section').each(function(i){
            if(WindowTop > $(this).offset().top - 50&& 
               WindowTop < $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(true)
              ){
                $('.nav > li > a').removeClass('newClass');
                $('.nav li').eq(i).find('a').addClass('newClass');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/umehyrza/7/)

Comment: What if one of the sections is a bit smaller? Like the contact us section. It doesn't work then...

Comment: this is good. only thing left is that when the menu item (for example About) is clicked it should also add the 'newClass' class to it, so long as the user is on the #About. When the user scrolls off the #About section, the class 'newClass' should be removed.

Comment: @JacquesMarais ( if one of the sections is a bit smaller) .. you can let me know if you found that code which will catch this section in scroll event